# How to know if a existing AWS ELB is either Classic or Application load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-load-balancer, engineyard

I got responsible for the management of a AWS account with a preexisting load balancer, and want to know if it is a Classic load balancer or an [application load balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/applicationloadbalancer/).

I could not find the information either through the web console or the [ruby API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ElasticLoadBalancing/Client.html)

Comment: The accepted answer solves through the web console. It would still be nice to know how to query programatically. I've noticed that there exists two modules [Aws::ElasticLoadBalancing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ElasticLoadBalancing.html) and [Aws::ElasticLoadBalancingV2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ElasticLoadBalancingV2.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the web console when you look at your list of load balancers there is a "**Type**" column that tells you which type it is.

Comment: Ends up it was lack of attention from me... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With [API V2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/index.html#cli-aws-elbv2) **describe-load-balancers** [command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-load-balancers.html) will give you the type of the ELB.

```
aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers --names my-load-balancer
```

**Type** will indicate the type of the ELB

```
{
  "LoadBalancers": [
  {
      "VpcId": "vpc-3ac0fb5f",
      "LoadBalancerArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:loadbalancer/app/my-load-balancer/50dc6c495c0c9188",
      "State": {
          "Code": "active"
      },
      "DNSName": "my-load-balancer-424835706.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com",

      "SecurityGroups": [
          "sg-5943793c"
      ],
      "LoadBalancerName": "my-load-balancer",
      "CreatedTime": "2016-03-25T21:26:12.920Z",
      "Scheme": "internet-facing",
      "Type": "application",
      "CanonicalHostedZoneId": "Z2P70J7EXAMPLE",
      "AvailabilityZones": [
          {
              "SubnetId": "subnet-8360a9e7",
              "ZoneName": "us-west-2a"
          },
          {
              "SubnetId": "subnet-b7d581c0",
              "ZoneName": "us-west-2b"
          }
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```